# why Flink framework doesn't use all slots available? should the dataset be in each taskmanager?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using VM and my cluster consists of 3 taskmanagers and the master is jobmanager and taskmanager too (4 taskmangers and one job manager) so
when I run the jar file it used just one slot and I have 4 slots about one slot for one task manager, I don't know why the framework doesn't use all slots available.
and I want to know should the dataset be in each taskmanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends somewhat on which cluster manager you are using (e.g., yarn, mesos, kubernetes, or standalone), but in general Flink does not support autoscaling (yet) and so you need to explicitly configure the desired parallelism. You can do this in the source code for the job, or in flink-conf.yaml, or on the command line. If you don't do this, then your jobs will run with the default parallelism.

As for where you should put the data, your flink application will read data using a source connector. If you are using a filesystem as the data source, then every taskmanager will need to be able to read the data using the same filesystem URI -- which is best accomplished by using a distributed filesystem.

Comment: sorry I'm new in this field, I'm using a standalone cluster manager so how I configure the desired parallelism and should the configuration be in each taskmanager or just in jobmanager.
and I'm not using a distributed filesystem for the data source so should I put the data in each taskmanager,isn't?

Comment: It's probably easiest to specify the parallelism when you submit the job, but you could set the default parallelism everywhere -- in the job manager and each task manager. The docs should help: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/cluster_setup.html

Comment: sorry, I couldn't adjust the parallelism in the flink-conf.ymal or in command line I got error :Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.exceptions.JobModificationException: Cannot rescale job CSVInteger (WikiTalk.txt) ⇨ PageRank ⇨ Print.
and if I set parallelism default more than one I got error and if I increase the taskslots equal the parallelism I don't have error but the job uses only one taskmanager